# why d3 line chart and bar chart display in same morment?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I use d3 bar chart and line chart in my web page.[line_chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)and[bar_chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) like following example.but in same situation it not show both of chart.it show only one chart.how to solve this problem.?please guild me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the *d3* bar chart_ and *line chart* at the same time you need to change the variable accordingly. If you use `var x` in *bar chart* you need to use another variable like `var x1`. I think this is the problem you face. Try it.